# How are Internet connections differentiated from each other by an operating system?

Tags: networking, internet-connection, tcp, packet

Given this example, how would my operating system differentiate between each request.

Let us say I have 3 tabs open, and at the same exact time, they all go to `http://google.com`. How would my operating system differentiate the reply data coming back? Would it not all be the exact same? In the TCP header, the source and destination ports will be the same along with the source and destination ip address along with the scheme (http).

I know IP packet headers have an ID header but is this not for dealing with fragmentation, not physically identifying a packet. Besides, IP packets should be conectionless correct?

In ICMP echo requests for example, the echo requests and responses have ID’s to match each packet to each response. How would this be done in my scenario then? My guess would be that data is sent in the TCP packet to differentiate but I am not sure.

Edit: I made a bad assumption. Just because a packet is being sent to port 80 does not mean the source needs to be port 80 as well. For example, looking at [this NAT example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCqP1.png), we can see this is not done. This allows the source segment to have a different source port for each request.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a client program (such as a browser) connects to a server,
it opens a socket. 
And (unless the program specifies one, which is very rare),
the operating system assigns a unique port number to the socket. 
This will commonly be in the range 1000-2000. 
The source IP is, of course, the address of the client host. 
The server determines the destination parameters;
e.g., the IP address of google.com, and 80.

So, you’re right; separate TCP connections from the same client machine
to the same server port are distinguished by different source port numbers. 
This has nothing to do with NAT.

You can see this if you examine the output of `netstat`.

Answer (score -1):

This is simpler if you look up some layers. Just remembering the life cycle of an HTTP request:

- The client browser initiates a socket connection to web server
- A request at http standard is sent to the server.
- The server processes the request and returns a response in the HTTP standard to the customer.
- The client browser receives the response.
- The connection to the server is closed.
- The browser client interprets the answer and displays on the screen the result

So when the browser opens a request it waits for a response. Considering the [keepalive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive) nature of a TCP/IP connection, this response occurs on the same connection. Then the browser can differentiate which request is for that tab.

Multiple connections are opened at the same time by the browser.

Comment: How does this answer the question? You say "this response occurs on the same connection . Then the browser can differentiate which request is for that tab." How can the client differentiate between the traffic for different tabs (or different browsers)? P.S. The differentiation isn't done by the browser(s); it's done by the operating system.

Comment: Who opens and closes using the socket connection is the browser. The operating system is limited to offering ways to do this through its api . His explanation of ports is relevant, but does not respond how differentiate a tab and another , after all is not the operating system that makes this differentiation . He only delivers a socket connection handle to the requestor. Not even know that that connection is in the HTTP standard . Who does this is the Browser . And yes ,request and response occours in the same connection